# Jquery .addClass and .removeClass Not Working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I wrote a code that clicking an item displays a context menu like div to enabling user to cut and paste a list item, I added disabled class to buttons in div that are related to paste operation. but when something selected I want to remove the class 'disable' to enable paste buttons. the code is as below:

**html:**

```
<div id="contextMenu" class="text-center" style="display: none; z-index: 1001; width: 242px;box-shadow:#D3D3D3 0px 0px 10px 4px; background-color: #FDFFC7; padding: 15px;">
<a class="btn btn-primary" style="margin: 3px 6px 3px 0px;" href="#" id="cut"><i class="fa fa-cut fa-lg"></i> Kes</a>
<div class="btn-group" style="margin: 3px 0px 3px 6px;">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success disabled" id="InsertInto" title="Kestiğini kategoriyi seçtiğiniz kategorinin içine yapıştırır."><i class="fa fa-paste fa-lg"></i> Yapıştır</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success dropdown-toggle disabled" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="#" title="Seçtiğiniz kategorinin Üstüne ekler" id="AddAbove"><i class="fa fa-level-up fa-lg"></i> Üstüne Ekle</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="Seçtiğiniz kategorinin Altına ekler" id="AddBelow"><i class="fa fa-level-down fa-lg"></i> Altına Ekle</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).on('click', '.ContextMenu', function () {
    event.preventDefault();

    var anySelected = $('.selected').length;

    if (anySelected > 0) {
        $("button", "#contextManu").removeClass('disabled');
    }

    var widgetPosition = $('#contextMenu').parent().offset();

    $('#contextMenu').css('position', 'absolute');
    var currentPosition = $(this).offset();                

    var contextLeft = (currentPosition.left) - $('#contextMenu').width() - widgetPosition.left - 10;
    var contextTop = (currentPosition.top + 80) - widgetPosition.top;
    $('#contextMenu').css('left', contextLeft);
    $('#contextMenu').css('top', contextTop);                

    $('#contextMenu').slideDown(300);

    $selectedListItem = $(this).parents('div.categoryItemContainer').parent();


});
```

I Trace code using google chrome browser, $("button", "#contextManu") founds two button in the contextMenu div but not changes it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have a typo in your selector at this line:

```
$("button", "#contextManu").removeClass('disabled');
```

`#contextManu` needs to have the `a` changed to an `e` like so:

```
$("button", "#contextMenu").removeClass('disabled');
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use toggleClass. I recently found that gem out myself.

```
$('button', '#contextMenu').toggleClass('disabled');
```

[From the docs:](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)
*Add or remove one or more classes from each element in the set of matched elements, depending on either the class's presence or the value of the switch argument.*

So, you don't even need to add "disabled" to your element(s) to begin with.